# Creating New record using Standard Controller and Extension

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I have created a page using standard controller and extension.

This page should create a record if no id passed and shuold update a record when id passed.

Following is the controller

```
public TestController(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) 
    {

        this.Test =   (Test__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();

        if(this.Test != null && this.Test.Id != null)        
        {
              this.Test = [   SELECT  Number__c,First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Message__c,Email__c
                                        FROM    Test__c
                                        WHERE   Id = : Test.Id];       
        }
        else
        {
            this.Test = new Test__c();
        }   
     }

public pageReference SaveandClose()
    {


        f(this.Test != null && this.Test.Id != null)   
        {
            update (this.Test);
        }        
        else
        {

            insert (this.Test);  
        }

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/t');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);

        return pageRef;   
    }
```

Visualforce Page code : testPage

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" id="page" standardController="Test__c"
    extensions="TestController">
<apex:pageBlock id="Details">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false">
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Test.First_Name__c}" required="true"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Test.Last_Name__c}" required="true"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Test.Number__c}" required="true"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Test.Email__c}" />
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Test.Message__c}" style="width:220px;height:150px"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:outputPanel layout="block">
                                <table>
                                    <tr style="position: fixed; bottom: 0" align="center">
                                        <td>
                                        <apex:commandButton value="Save and Close"
                                                action="{!SaveandClose}"
                                                immediate="true" /> 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

I am able to edit the record. But i am not able to create new one. 
I have a New button on one page and also Edit button which redirects me to this page.

```
pageReference pageRef = new pageReference('/testPage');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',test.id);
```

Comment: whats the error

Comment: Its not showing any error in debug log... ApexPages.StandardController.getRecord() -- its giving as false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go with the `Upsert` Option. Upsert can be used in places where you are not sure if you'll have the Id of the Object and you want to insert/update the record.

If the object doesn't have an Id, it performs an insert and if it has, it does an update call.

```
   public pageReference SaveandClose()
    {
        try{
            upsert this.Test;
        }        
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error creating/updating record'));
        }
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/t');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);

        return pageRef;   
    }
```

Also, as a side note, always have DML statements in a try-catch block since you might not know when you would run into DML errors from validation rules, triggers, etc.,

Comment: I am not getting any error in DML statement.. Its giving error when i am opening the page without passing any id to the page ... I guess since i am using standard controller i have to pass record id. But i what if i want to create a new record

Comment: Why do you need a standard controller? You can test if id is empty using Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') instead of using standard controller. This should not give you error on load.

Comment: ohkk.. will try this approach.. Could you please give me some sample code for this

Comment: Its working now